Two Factor Authenticator SignIn with API in C#
I have 2 projects: Client and API and use IdentityDbContext
When I login and enable 2FA, it returns true for the Client to navigate through Page LoginWith2fa
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: true);
if (result.IsLockedOut)
{
    return StatusCode(423, new { message = "User account locked out" });
}
if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
{
    return Ok(new
    {
        RequiresTwoFactor = true,
    });
}

But I don't know what to do on the LoginWith2fa page
I tried generating an identity for this page and found that using _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
But it is in the Client project
I hope the LoginWith2fa page will call the API to the API project to handle that
I have tried when login with the account RequiresTwoFactor with this code
var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(request.UserName, request.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: true);
if (!signInResult.RequiresTwoFactor) 
{ 
    return Unauthorized(new { message = "Not Enable 2FA" });
}

var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(request.VerificationCode, true, true);
if (result.IsLockedOut)
{
    return StatusCode(423, new { message = "User account locked out" });
}
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return Ok(new {Message="Success Login"})
}

But it always Failure

so is you question how to implement 2FA? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity

I need how to implement 2FA but with Authentication App
var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(request.VerificationCode, true, true);
when I read to GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync It get userId from await Context.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme);

So I have test when login with password return RequiresTwoFactor = true It will login by authentication code like below
if (!signInResult.RequiresTwoFactor) 
{ 
    return Unauthorized(new { message = "Not Enable 2FA" });
}

var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(request.VerificationCode, true, true);```
@Quak_2023
